# How can I perform clicks on some links to get to the target page?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to perform click on some links to get to the target page. However, the links are stored within javascript encrypted html elements. How can I make a conventional 'href' link out of those elements so that it is possible to make a click on that to get to the target page? At this moment I'm getting some numbers as 'href', much like 'javascript:getDetail(19978)'.
Here Is what I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/')

driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm').send_keys('All')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
time.sleep(3)
for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a'):
    print(items.get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
```

Elements within which href links should be stored:

```
<td><a href="javascript:getDetail(19978)">GOLD DUST FLYING SERVICE, INC.</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute script method like below,

```
driver.execute_script("javascript:getDetail(19978)")
```

or

```
driver.execute_script(items.get_attribute('href'))
```

or simply try with,

```
item.click();
```